# World Time Widget - Display the time in a city

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement a world time widget that will allow a user to select a city, hit a button and display the time in that city for them.

Has anyone got any pointers for me please?

Comment: Do you have a specific list of cities or will it be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the TimeZoneInfo class ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)).  This class, introduced in .net 3.5 handles most of the heavy lifting for you.

The steps to do what you're asking is as follows:

1. In your dropdown list of cities, set the value for each city as their TimeZoneInfo DisplayName.  See here for how to use the [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx). This will take a bit of work but, thanksfully, you'll only have to do this once.
2. When a user selects a city, use the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx) to convert the time and you're done.

There are several different methods in the TimeZoneInfo class and a closer inspection will get you to your solution.

Comment: Just found this class yesterday, looks like it will be a good fit.

Comment: You accepted the answer but did not award the bounty points.  Is there something more that you are waiting for from the answer?

Comment: @LuisEValencia sorry I don't have access to the code any longer Alisons example above got me 90% of the way there if I remember

Answer (score 2):

You could use some [existing API](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/time_zone_guide/) allowing you to fetch the time given a city name. Another possibility is download [World Time Zones database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) locally and integrate in your application.